# C++ library for IMAP

Tags: library, email, c++, imap

What C++ libraries (if any) are available that handle the IMAP email protocol? I'm looking for something similar to [Python's imaplib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imaplib.html), which allows you to do this from Python:

```
import getpass, imaplib
M = imaplib.IMAP4()
M.login(getpass.getuser(), getpass.getpass())
M.select()
typ, data = M.search(None, 'ALL')
for num in data[0].split():
    typ, data = M.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
    print 'Message %s\n%s\n' % (num, data[0][1])
M.close()
M.logout()
```

So I'm looking for a C++ library that allows equivalent functionality.

Answer (score 2):

VMime is a C++ email library that supports IMAP as well as POP3 and SMTP.

Webpage: https://www.vmime.org

GitHub: https://github.com/kisli/vmime

Features:

- It is free, GNU GPL licensed software
- Fully RFC compliant implementation
- Modular design
- Easy to use and intuitive design
- Well documented C++ code
- Highly reliable
- Maximum portability